# What type should I use for a 128-bit number in in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, int128

I need to do some large integer math.  Are there any classes or structs out there that represent a 128-bit integer and implement all of the usual operators?

BTW, I realize that `decimal` can be used to represent a 96-bit int.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to work with such large numbers?

Comment: Note that a native unsigned int128 would be a natural representation of an IPv6 address, adding to urgency and relevance of this question

Comment: There's a question in C++ that does discuss this in more detail, specifically how to simulate Int128 addition and subtraction http://stackoverflow.com/a/741371/58961

Comment: Int128 and UInt128 will be in .NET 7 (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/#types-without-language-support and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67151)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**It's here in [System.Numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0)**.  "The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower bounds."

```
var i = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse("10000000000000000000000000000000");
```

Comment: Okay, so a BigInteger satisfies that need but it's not a Int128 type, it does heap allocations (a lot of 'em, per operation) and operates on 32-bit words, there's overhead in something like that and while it supports an arbitrary range, I wouldn't use that if I knew I really needed an Int128 type. I reckon people have been using smaller sized integers to simulate a larger sized integer for some time (due to various hardware restrictions) and it shouldn't be to hard to find the appropriate C code and adapt that. My point is, BigInteger is a solution to the general case, not Int128 specifically.

Comment: FYI: BigInteger is not available for .NET 2

Comment: BigInteger ≠ Int128

Comment: use two qwords (`long`) instead of biginteger if you are after performance.

Answer (score 61):

While `BigInteger` is the best solution for most applications, if you have performance critical numerical computations, you can use the complete `Int128` and `UInt128` implementations in my [**Dirichlet.Numerics**](https://github.com/ricksladkey/dirichlet-numerics) library.  These types are useful if `Int64` and `UInt64` are too small but `BigInteger` is too slow.

Comment: This most accurately answers the question, and in a very helpful way.

Comment: Your uint128 has four ulong fields causing it to use 32 bytes. Why does it need the two extra ulong?

Comment: No, it has two ulong fields. Certain operations (such as modular multiplication) require 256 bit accuracy for intermediate results, so a representation for UInt256 is also necessary. That private type does indeed (and must have) have four ulong fields.

Comment: I'm not used to that coding style so just to make sure, did you write just like in C++ by using `ref` and `out` to avoid `pass-by-value` allocations since `UInt128` is a struct ? Very nice library btw.

Comment: very poor, naive and slow implementation

Answer (score 31):

[`System.Int128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0) and [`System.UInt128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0) have been available since .NET Core 7.0 Preview 5

They were implemented in [Add support for Int128 and UInt128 data types](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67151)

I don't know why they aren't in the [.NET 7 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-preview-5/) [announcement](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7441) but in the upcoming .NET 7 Preview 6 announcement there'll also be [`Int128Converter` and `UInt128Converter`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7454) for the new types in Preview 5

They didn't have [C# support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/#types-without-language-support) yet though, just like `System.Half`, so you'll have to use `Int128` explicitly instead of using a native C# keyword

Comment: how would **you** name int128 ? Huge? ;) what would be int256 then ?? :))

Comment: @BoppityBop `llong`, which is kind of common in various libraries. `extended` is also common in C. Or look at delphi with [its silly names like `Cardinal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63156176/995714)

Answer (score 15):

No, there's nothing in .NET <= 3.5. I'm hoping/expecting that [BigInteger](https://web.archive.org/web/20070120081853/http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/01/16/introducing-system-numeric-biginteger-inbar-gazit.aspx) will make its return in .NET 4.0. (It was [cut from .NET 3.5](https://web.archive.org/web/20080107113836/http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/01/04/where-did-biginteger-go-melitta-andersen.aspx).)

Comment: It was actually [reintroduced in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) and is still around.

Comment: @DrewNoakes: Indeed - shame BigDecimal remained cut though :(

Comment: @markshep: Agreed, although I'd argue that adding a copy/paste comment to almost all answers isn't actually a good idea. But for someone wanting to work with large integers, `BigInteger` is likely to be the best solution. Extra work would be required to make it overflow in the same way as an Int128, of course.

Answer (score 6):

`BigInteger` is now a standard part of C# and friends in .NET 4.0. See: [Gunnar Peipman's ASP.NET blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/05/23/net-framework-4-0-introducing-biginteger.aspx).

Note that the CPU can generally work with ordinary integers much more quickly and in constant time, especially when using the usual math operators (+, -, /, ...) because these operators typically map directly to single CPU instructions.

With `BigInteger`, even the most basic math operations are much slower function calls to methods whose runtime varies with the size of the number. This is because `BigInteger` implements arbitrary precision arithmetic, which adds considerable but necessary overhead.
The benefit is that BigIntegers are not limited to 64 or even 128 bits, but by available system memory (or about 2<sup>64</sup> bits of precision, whichever comes first).
Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @markshep: I realize that, but BigInteger fulfills the requirement, `I need to do some large integer math.`
I think my mistake was in not mentioning that it fulfill the requirement, `implement[s] all of the usual operators"`. I have edited the answer to reflect this, and added some notes on arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Comment: What do you mean by "Note that BigInteger does not support the usual operators"?

Comment: @AluanHaddad: I had meant that BigInteger operators were overloaded, not just simple 1:1 mappings with a CPU instruction, but that was clear as mud so I rewrote that part of the post.

Answer (score 4):

GUID is backed by a 128 bit integer in .NET framework; though it doesn't come with any of the typical integer type methods.

I've written a handler for GUID before to treat it as a 128 bit integer, but this was for a company I worked for ~8 years ago. I no longer have access to the source code.

So if you need native support for a 128 bit integer, and don't want to rely on BigInteger for whatever reason, you could probably hack GUID to server your purposes.

Comment: That would be okay for storage, but if I wanted to add, subtract, multiply, etc, I'd probably be better using something else

Comment: Correct. We were using it as a bit mask (updated column in database from 64bit to guid), so storage was all we needed it for. Time constraints of feature improvement lead to the hacky solution.

Answer (score 3):

If  you don't mind making reference to the J# library (vjslib.dll included with VS by default) there is already and implementation of BigInteger in .NET

```
using java.math;

public static void Main(){
    BigInteger biggy = new BigInteger(....)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

C# PCL library for computations with big numbers such as Int128 and Int256.
https://github.com/lessneek/BigMath

Comment: Unfortunately, it performs some heap allocations during multiplication.

Comment: unfortunately the link has died. Probably the library has been removed

Comment: @phuclv I have corrected the link to my old repo.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov you can improve the code and push.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 7 introduced `Int128` (and `UInt128`)

You can use them as built-in native primitives now, just like you would `int` or `long`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 0):

.NET 8 has added `Int128` and `UInt128` to `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`.
These two types `Int128` and `UInt128` were introduced in .NET 7

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    [ Int128.MaxValue, UInt128.MaxValue ]
));
// [170141183460469231731687303715884105727,340282366920938463463374607431768211455]
```

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-8.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-8.0

Answer (score -3):

I believe Mono has a BigInteger implementation that you should be able to track down the source for.