# How can I add and subtract 128 bit integers in C or C++ if my compiler does not support them?

Tags: c++, integer, 128-bit

I'm writing a compressor for a long stream of 128 bit numbers. I would like to store the numbers as differences -- storing only the difference between the numbers rather than the numbers themselves because I can pack the differences in fewer bytes because they are smaller.

However, for compression then I need to subtract these 128 bit values, and for decompression I need to add these values. Maximum integer size for my compiler is 64 bits wide.

Anyone have any ideas for doing this efficiently?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If all you need is addition and subtraction, and you already have your 128-bit values in binary form, a library might be handy but isn't strictly necessary. This math is trivial to do yourself.

I don't know what your compiler uses for 64-bit types, so I'll use INT64 and UINT64 for signed and unsigned 64-bit integer quantities.

```
class Int128
{
public:
    ...
    Int128 operator+(const Int128 & rhs)
    {
        Int128 sum;
        sum.high = high + rhs.high;
        sum.low = low + rhs.low;
        // check for overflow of low 64 bits, add carry to high
        if (sum.low < low)
            ++sum.high;
        return sum;
    }
    Int128 operator-(const Int128 & rhs)
    {
        Int128 difference;
        difference.high = high - rhs.high;
        difference.low = low - rhs.low;
        // check for underflow of low 64 bits, subtract carry to high
        if (difference.low > low)
            --difference.high;
        return difference;
    }

private:
    INT64  high;
    UINT64 low;
};
```

Comment: You could just use stdint.h.

Answer (score 16):

Take a look at [GMP](http://gmplib.org/manual/).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    mpz_t x, y, z;
    char *xs, *ys, *zs;
    int i;
    int base[4] = {2, 8, 10, 16};

    /* setting the value of x in base 10 */
    mpz_init_set_str(x, "100000000000000000000000000000000", 10);

    /* setting the value of y in base 16 */
    mpz_init_set_str(y, "FF", 16);

    /* just initalizing the result variable */
    mpz_init(z);

    mpz_sub(z, x, y);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        xs = mpz_get_str(NULL, base[i], x);
        ys = mpz_get_str(NULL, base[i], y);
        zs = mpz_get_str(NULL, base[i], z);

        /* print all three in base 10 */
        printf("x = %s\ny = %s\nz = %s\n\n", xs, ys, zs);

        free(xs);
        free(ys);
        free(zs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
x = 10011101110001011010110110101000001010110111000010110101100111011111000000100000000000000000000000000000000
y = 11111111
z = 10011101110001011010110110101000001010110111000010110101100111011111000000011111111111111111111111100000001

x = 235613266501267026547370040000000000
y = 377
z = 235613266501267026547370037777777401

x = 100000000000000000000000000000000
y = 255
z = 99999999999999999999999999999745

x = 4ee2d6d415b85acef8100000000
y = ff
z = 4ee2d6d415b85acef80ffffff01
```

Comment: Will definitely keep this library in mind if I need more than addition and subtraction. Thanks!

Comment: GMP comes with a C++ interface (`#include <gmpxx.h>`) that is much simpler to use...

Answer (score 8):

Having stumbled across this relatively old post entirely by accident, I thought it pertinent to elaborate on Volte's previous conjecture for the benefit of inexperienced readers.

Firstly, the signed range of a 128-bit number is -2<sup>127</sup> to 2<sup>127</sup>-1 and not -2<sup>127</sup> to 2<sup>127</sup> as originally stipulated.

Secondly, due to the cyclic nature of finite arithmetic the largest required differential between two 128-bit numbers is -2<sup>127</sup> to 2<sup>127</sup>-1, which has a storage prerequisite of 128-bits, not 129.  Although (2<sup>127</sup>-1) - (-2<sup>127</sup>) = 2<sup>128</sup>-1 which is clearly greater than our maximum 2<sup>127</sup>-1 positive integer, arithmetic overflow always ensures that the nearest distance between any two *n*-bit numbers always falls within the range 0 to 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1 and thus implicitly -2<sup>*n*-1</sup> to 2<sup>*n*-1</sup>-1.

In order to clarify, let us first examine how a hypothetical 3-bit processor would implement binary addition.  As an example, consider the following table which depicts the absolute unsigned range of a 3-bit integer.

0 = 000b
   1 = 001b
   2 = 010b
   3 = 011b
   4 = 100b
   5 = 101b
   6 = 110b
   7 = 111b ---> [Cycles back to 000b on overflow]

From the above table it is readily apparent that:

001b(1) + 010b(2) = 011b(3)

It is also apparent that adding any of these numbers with its numeric complement always yields 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1:

010b(2) + 101b([complement of 2] = 5) = 111b(7) = (2<sup>3</sup>-1)

Due to the cyclic overflow which occurs when the addition of two *n*-bit numbers results in an (*n*+1)-bit result, it therefore follows that adding any of these numbers with its numeric complement + 1 will always yield 0:

010b(2) + 110b([complement of 2] + 1) = 000b(0)

Thus we can say that [complement of *n*] + 1 = -*n*, so that *n* + [complement of *n*] + 1 = *n* + (-*n*) = 0.   Furthermore, if we now know that *n* + [complement of *n*] + 1 = 0, then *n* + [complement of  *n* - *x*]  + 1 must = *n* - (*n*-*x*) = *x*.

Applying this to our original 3-bit table yields:

0 = 000b = [complement of 0] + 1 = 0
   1 = 001b = [complement of 7] + 1 = -7
   2 = 010b = [complement of 6] + 1 = -6
   3 = 011b = [complement of 5] + 1 = -5
   4 = 100b = [complement of 4] + 1 = -4
   5 = 101b = [complement of 3] + 1 = -3
   6 = 110b = [complement of 2] + 1 = -2
   7 = 111b = [complement of 1] + 1 = -1 ---> [Cycles back to 000b on overflow]

Whether the representational abstraction is positive, negative or a combination of both as implied with signed twos-complement arithmetic, we now have 2<sup>*n*</sup> *n*-bit patterns which can seamlessly serve both positive 0 to 2<sup>*n*</sup>-1 and negative 0 to -(2<sup>*n*</sup>)-1 ranges as and when required.  In point of fact, all modern processors employ just such a system in order to implement common ALU circuitry for both addition and subtraction operations.  When a CPU encounters an `i1 - i2` subtraction instruction, it internally performs a [complement + 1] operation on `i2` and subsequently processes the operands through the addition circuitry in order to compute `i1` + [complement of `i2`] + 1.  With the exception of an additional carry/sign XOR-gated overflow flag, both signed and unsigned addition, and by implication subtraction, are each implicit.

If we apply the above table to the input sequence [-2<sup>*n*-1</sup>, 2<sup>*n*-1</sup>-1, -2<sup>*n*-1</sup>] as presented in Volte's original reply, we are now able to compute the following n-bit differentials:

diff #1:
   (2<sup>*n*-1</sup>-1) - (-2<sup>*n*-1</sup>) =
   3 - (-4) = 3 + 4 =
   (-1) = 7 = 111b

diff #2:
   (-2<sup>*n*-1</sup>) - (2<sup>*n*-1</sup>-1) =
   (-4) - 3 = (-4) + (5) =
   (-7) = 1 = 001b

Starting with our seed -2<sup>*n*-1</sup>, we are now able to reproduce the original input sequence by applying each of the above differentials sequentially:

(-2<sup>*n*-1</sup>) + (diff #1) =
   (-4) + 7 = 3 =
   2<sup>*n*-1</sup>-1

(2<sup>*n*-1</sup>-1) + (diff #2) =
   3 + (-7) = (-4) =
   -2<sup>*n*-1</sup>

You may of course wish to adopt a more philosophical approach to this problem and conjecture as to why 2<sup>*n*</sup> cyclically-sequential numbers would require more than 2<sup>*n*</sup> cyclically-sequential differentials?

Taliadon.

Comment: I have to say I understand about 5% of that post. I can confirm that using the algorithm I described allowed me to achieve about 20% compression of the CLSIDs in my whitelist.

Answer (score 8):

Boost 1.53 now includes multiprecision:

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <iostream>

// Requires Boost 1.53 or higher
// build: g++ text.cpp

int main()
{
    namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

    mp::uint128_t a = 4294967296;
    mp::uint256_t b(0);
    mp::uint512_t c(0);

    b = a * a;
    c = b * b;

    std::cout << "c: " << c << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
c: 340282366920938463463374607431768211456
```

Comment: Easily the best answer. Boost has drop-in replacements for native types such as double. The Boost docs are a great read, and provide lots of nice sample code.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of literature regarding large integer math. You can use one of the libraries freely available (see links) or you can roll your own. Although I should warn you, for anything more complicated than addition and subtraction (and shifts), you'll need to use non-trivial algorithms.

To add and subtract, you can create a class/structure that holds two 64-bit integers. You can use simple school math to do the addition and subtraction. Basically, do what you do with a pencil and paper to add or subtract, with careful consideration to carries/borrows.

Search for large integer. Btw recent versions of VC++, IntelC++ and GCC compilers have 128-bit integer types, although I'm not sure they are as easily accessible as you might like (they are intended to be used with sse2/xmms registers).

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_precision_arithmetic
- http://orion.math.iastate.edu/cbergman/crypto/bignums.html
- http://www.mathgoodies.com/tutorial/

Comment: If I try to use my compiler's __int128 type I get this message:
c:\...\clsidcompressor.h(5) : error C4235: nonstandard extension used : '__int128' keyword not supported on this architecture

Comment: You probably have changed the target to something that doesn't have the aforementioned sse2/xmms registers, and therefore make no sense to use __int128. Try searching the documentation to see if you can use them at all. Otherwise, there are really a lot of small libraries that will do the job.

Comment: Visual Studio won't use __int128 on x86 or x64.

Comment: The 128 bit integers are completely unrelated to SSE, they only use the basic ALU on x86.

Answer (score 2):

[TomsFastMath](http://www.libtom.net/TomsFastMath/) is a bit like GMP (mentioned above), but is public domain, and was designed from the ground up to be extremely fast (it even contains assembly code optimizations for x86, x86-64, ARM, SSE2, PPC32, and AVR32).

Comment: GMP is under the LGPL, so you can do anything a rational person would want to do: http://gmplib.org/manual/Copying.html#Copying

Comment: LGPL still has some requirements that might make one think twice:  you need to provide the capability for the user to be able to relink your application with an updated/custom/different version of the LGPL'ed library.

Comment: @Michael: Think of the L as "shared library" rather than anything else.  If your app is dynamically linked then you have already provided the necessary ability to relink because it's possible to put a new shared library in the lib path.

Comment: Why would it need updating if it has a simple goal and does it well?

Answer (score 2):

Also worth noting: if the goal is merely to improve the compression of a stream of numbers by preprocessing it, then the preprocessed stream doesn't have to be made of exactly arithmetic differences.  You can use XOR (`^`) instead of `+` and `-`.  The advantage is that a 128-bit XOR is exactly the same as two independent XORs on the 64-bit parts, so it is both simple and efficient.