# How to properly add/subtract a 128-bit number (as two uint64_t)?

Tags: c, math, int128

I'm working in C and need to add and subtract a 64-bit number and a 128-bit number. The result will be held in the 128-bit number. I am using an integer array to store the upper and lower halves of the 128-bit number (i.e. `uint64_t bigNum[2]`, where `bigNum[0]` is the least significant).

Can anybody help with an addition and subtraction function that can take in bigNum and add/subtract a `uint64_t` to it?

I have seen many incorrect examples on the web, so consider this:

```
bigNum[0] = 0;  
bigNum[1] = 1;  
subtract(&bigNum, 1);
```

At this point `bigNum[0]` should have all bits set, while `bigNum[1]` should have no bits set.

Comment: FYI: existing libraries such as GMP (http://gmplib.org/) can already take care of that.  So if there is no particular reason to avoid it, I would recommend using existing code.  And if you want to know how to do it yourself, you can look into the source code of GMP.

Comment: I fail to understand your example. Isn't 1 - 1 = 0, not -1?

Comment: GMP is giant bloat for just 128-bit integer support. Also it can randomly `abort()` your program.

Comment: External libraries in general are too large and unnecessary. I am doing simple math only. Also as for the 1 - 1 = 0 question... the bytes are little-endian (least significant byte first). So it would really be (1<<32)-1 = 0xffffffff, hope that helps?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add and subtract 128 bit integers in C or C++ if my compiler does not support them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741301/how-can-i-add-and-subtract-128-bit-integers-in-c-or-c-if-my-compiler-does-not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In grade 1 or 2, you should have learn't how to break down the addition of 1 and 10 into parts, by splitting it into multiple separate additions of tens and units. When dealing with big numbers, the same principals can be applied to compute arithmetic operations on arbitrarily large numbers, by realizing your units are now units of 2^bits, your "tens" are 2^bits larger and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In many architectures it's very easy to add/subtract any arbitrarily-long integers because there's a [carry flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag) and *add/sub-with-flag* instruction. For example on x86 `rdx:rax += r8:r9` can be done like this

```
add rax, r9    # add the low parts and store the carry
adc rdx, r8    # add the high parts with carry
```

In C there's no way to access this carry flag so you must calculate the flag on your own. The easiest way is to check if the ***unsigned** sum is less than either of the operand* [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/741371/995714). For example to do `a += b` we'll do

```
aL += bL;
aH += bH + (aL < bL);
```

This is **exactly** how multi-word add is done in architectures that don't have a [flag register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register). For example in MIPS it's done [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_register#CPU_architectures_without_arithmetic_flags)

```
    # alow = blow + clow
addu    alow, blow, clow
    # set tmp = 1 if alow < clow, else 0
sltu    tmp, alow, clow
addu    ahigh, bhigh, chigh
addu    ahigh, ahigh, tmp
```

Here's some [example assembly output](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMxmpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQBpAAOqAqETgwe3r4BQSlpjgJhEdEscQn%2Btpj2hQxCBEzEBFk%2BfoFVNRn1jQTFUbHxiQoNTS057cM9faXlAQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2B4cjeWADUJv5uw/iCAHQIB9gmGgCC1zdeDGnAEei7APrv4QRcZgAcuyY6HQEEez1eHy%2Bgl%2BANUpF2YLwL0wb0%2B3xhuwAnnN7iYAOxWW67Ym7YiYAjLBi7VT7SxYg6Eu54gAiuNuw2IXgcCPR/32BPuJJ5ggAbJJ3gRdgAJBmCkleb5iiW7EKy2741n%2BRkK6F8oHoMyg3kApjwnU/PkxHHqgVEklMU4hWlWfzM3YxR1qm5Ch1S50HN0ev3WXYQB1Og5ud2OnFauXEskU4hUphejX3DgLWicACsvD8HC0pFQnDc1hDCiWK0wtP8PFIBE0mYWCEwQMGEAWAGsQGYuKdJH8/iK8XX/ABOLg5v45vE5/ScSS8FgSDQaUgFoslji8BQgdeNwuZ0hwWAwRAoVAsJJ0eLkShoa%2B3hJJJLIMX0YC/Mzrmi0AjxHuEAxE2pAxOEjSYpw9aPmwggAPIMLQUFHqQWAsIYwDiKh%2BBkg4eAAG6YHuqGYKomDIF4AHQbw3zVKBtB4DExCQR4WA0Q2xB4Cu3DHlQBjAAoABqeCYAA7vBSSMBx/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqKhuhBAYRgoOWlj6Exe6QAsqBJLUJEALTwf4uwWSwZIvKwxG8EkhhRE5nApGJ8QfjWwDIMguy/Kc/ZFnYFG1C4DDuJ4rR6KE4T9GUgxcMkqTpAIYx%2BKl%2BQZQw0wDAkqXhfhAjdKMsU5MV1QRV0Iy9IlMwpbY9VZXokxNAVyVFQslbLKsegEGSaw8Fmub5qB25eT5kj0Ls/mBcFoW8IeWgLBASCPje9BkBQEBbc%2BICNCwYpfmYP58HQAHEEBIGoeBzDEChMFXnBBCIchoHoZh2FFrhtVESRRZkRRVEjbRgj0ahjHMaxGDg5x3E0Qs/FMIJIniZJ0m8cpwiiOISmyfIShqKBuiVNpxh6TYMNGZ2xZmRklnWS5bmRB5HA3AASgAsmK80BUFZinMLYU1aVfgQK4bWpQlJSFXouW1DLaUFBkXWzNVnRla1lXZR0tU61MjUK8VuvZPrHUNfL3USL1VYDalQ2YODY0cHmG6TZw3N85IAuLcLosrU262bVe213ntB07SALB4EkCind%2Bv5XYBlB3UWD2QRxsGMO9SEoX9mAYUYv28P9%2BGA6BIOUdRON0dm0NMSxT1sQjQ1I7xKMCcJokSVJBb1kT8kE9IROqaTGkgNIlO6ZY1gGTEdMmYzAjM/4rMlBzccJ/zC1CyLpxi9rkvS3r8XRRrzVKxkKs30UJu21rht1ObcXPxL5XW0lmstT0KtWyvj1RY/VFKcRdsjBc7sJqoW3DvROft97BSDg2EOJ4w5Ph2vefa4dDrEAImKCyC1k6XX/GnYCoEs5PRzq9POH1C7l2Lj9NYf08B4UcFXUi5Fa4IwbgxZucN2KoQ7jxUafAe4Y37tjIesgR6KTHrICe6kiy6D%2BPoTCc8rD6VpvAFe5lOBWQ3skNmHMuYAEkhBuAskJUkBDJD%2BX9gfFBJVIpS2iirOWP9r7pWVufHKPj1aP1/i4uq/8/EG0/vVIB7U35VT/p1IJKV7agMGsNSBjcPabl4NucxljrG2NOoFJBgcj7ByPHMbsIBpynHHH8SQeIGkilnJOEUfwpxQKXKQFcOZ1xZOLJwXcvZUHlJPOeDal5MGRwfLgmOeAAo/j7CKFOZCbrp0oRBahONc4IQLl9JhpcWHlzYQDYi1duFgw4nwpusNW7w1AiIyBqN0Z9yxoPXgw98byNxkosmIA8TqJ0qYee2jDK6IZvojghjN7uTYJwVQw4LL8zmYFBZ/YRSlIia4s%2BFsL7oGif4tWmVwn33yokoqmLQkVRxR/WoX98XxOaOEwBZK7YgOrKkiBXcoGZK9hweFIpEV%2B2RbsVFpx0VFlWsecZ0cpk4MmQkbYmEpxrlIddW66zHrPV4Ns/On0cL7KwoctCxzK6nK4aDOu9YrlFhhi3TEbd7lcVEXxCRLyB4yVkZ8iQCiVIk2UToEAIoAVU2BTTUFxlwVMwMSzYxW9YV8oRfzRVRggo5iPhikJzg3ExWpcES%2BLKCV5TvgEh%2BNtgni1pbEy2FbKXfyauSq2ACokFuSeyp2aSuUZJgVuOFia/bJuAKm9NEq0HSpmbKmVCQ5mqAWX2ZZaq1n3Q2Vq0gOr6F7JLoar6JqOFmuBucy1EMAKNxtQI25Qj6wPK5U83umN3U4w%2BQpb13y/W/PnLPIFWiw1LzBaZCFULY0wrWPywVuxp0io0OdEKGaa1Zuxe/PNeKC2qyLcSktpKy3NUza/MJubsN0uQ42plzbMPAL6m28BrtuXduyb2gVSLkA0lndBkdIyx3yuwZOkAZ0gh/gXRQpdmqaEsDeuu/Vm6y7GvYYRPdvAa4XPrpDE9vBbWCPbk6x5rq73SPeZ6p9hNFGvqnqlD91NF7L0jWvaNRjXJxuA32xxyDdywdPu48Jnj62K3Q8WwlGGvENpc1/ABgWSP%2BZibhhDzLSOsvI47Sj6Txqe1gXR0DxSRZlLWi2NsWAEj00bp07pvTeWDKdiHSpeI/inBzFwLggRWlLLqVILSnAjF9O3Bl5sUCzDLlXEV5LO5hmZdIERG6GRp5AA%3D%3D)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for the subtraction:

```
typedef u_int64_t bigNum[2];

void subtract(bigNum *a, u_int64_t b)
{
  const u_int64_t borrow = b > a[1];

  a[1] -= b;
  a[0] -= borrow;
}
```

Addition is very similar. The above could of course be expressed with an explicit test, too, but I find it cleaner to always do the borrowing. Optimization left as an exercise.

For a `bigNum` equal to `{ 0, 1 }`, subtracting two would make it equal `{ ~0UL, ~0UL }`, which is the proper bit pattern to represent -1. Here, UL is assumed to promote an integer to 64 bits, which is compiler-dependent of course.

Comment: A hint for optimization: Some (most?) assembler instruction sets can give information on carry bits from addition and subtraction :-)

Comment: I don't believe that will compile... perhaps you meant borrow = b>>a[1];? However, I don't see how that would give the correct answer.

Comment: `b > a[1]` is a valid expression in C which returns 1 if true and 0 if false. You need to read some books about C basics again.

Answer (score 0):

For the case the value that your are subtracting is less or equal to `bignum[0]` you don't have to touch `bignum[1]`.

If it isn't, you subtract it from  `bignum[0]`, anyhow. This operation will wrap around, but this is the behavior you need here. In addition you'd then have to substact 1 from `bignum[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Most compilers support a [__int128](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) type intrinsically.

Try it and you might be lucky.

Comment: It would seem gcc's implementation of __int128 is machine dependent and only supported when long long is 128 bits wide. If that is wrong, please correct me.

Comment: @JoeBoo `long long` is always 64 bits on current systems. `__int128` is a separate type which is often only available on 64-bit systems