# Double integer precision multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, integer, multiplication

Is there any standard C++ way (e.g. class library) which provides integer multiplication with double precision? What I mean is: given two unsigned int's a,b the multiplication of them should give me an array of two unsigned int's {c, d} such that a*b = c + d*(UINT_MAX+1) ?

Comment: Are you talking about fixed point multiplication?

Comment: No, I guess not. I am talking about multiplication of natural numbers. Fixed point means that you have numbers in decimal notation with a fixed number of positions before and after the comma, isn't it? Idon't have any comma here.

Answer (score 1):

[GMP could be an option](http://gmplib.org/#WHAT)

Comment: Or code your own, I found switching to double (real - fp type) to afford sufficient precision for my needs, but got close to coding my own :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are restricted to the C++ standard libraries, the answer is no, there is no such predefined type. You can confirm that [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/). @DumbCoder suggested an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solves the problem, but as a crude built-in solution, you may try to use `unsigned long long int`, which is a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Not guaranteed to be portable though.

Comment: Don't you mean `unsigned long long`? @John Silver: `unsigned long long` was added to C++0x, so it is now part of the standard.

Comment: `unsigned long long int` and `unsigned long long` are names for the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried this with g++, but `unsigned long long (int)` seems to have the same size as `UINT_MAX.` (Which results in 1 if you multiply `UINT_MAX * UINT_MAX`).

Comment: @Christian: you should multiply `((unsigned long long)UINT_MAX) * UINT_MAX`. The type of an arithmetic expression only depends on the types of the operands, not the type you store it in: http://www.ideone.com/yvw0U

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. Although I am not sure whether `long long` is compiler independent. However with g++ it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

The [BigInt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/) class lets you work with arbitrary precision integers.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with splitting up the multiplication into pieces, except where you had h=(UINT_MAX+1)/2 it should be h=sqrt(UINT_MAX+1). If you have 32-bit integers for example h=0x10000. Multiplying by such a constant is the same as shifting left by a number of bits, so your equation becomes:

```
a0 = a & 0xffff;
a1 = a >> 16;
b0 = b & 0xffff;
b1 = b >> 16;
a*b = a0*b0 + ((a1*b0)<<16 + (a0*b1)<<16) + (a1*b1)<<32
```

Since each component is 16 bits or less, each multiplication is guaranteed to fit into an unsigned 32 bit result.

For adding multiple-precision values together, see [How can I add and subtract 128 bit integers in C or C++ if my compiler does not support them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741301/add-and-subtract-128-bit-integers-in-c/741371#741371)