# C# Custom data type!

Tags: c#, types, constructor, int128

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Int128 in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net)

After I decided to implement my Int128 in C#, I thought it would be nice to make it look like other dotNet data types.. But I could not implement the following feature:

- suffix initialization: such as 13L and 0.2D

Can I make my own suffix in C#?
And if I can not.. how can I initialize it?
i.e

```
Int128 a= ??
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot create your own suffix initializers - this is part of the language and baked into the compiler. If you write your own C# compiler, on the other hand, you can do whatever you want and extend it in whichever way you wish.

As for how you would initialize it - it depends on how you wrote it. If it is a class, you would need to initialize it with the `new` keyword, or write some implicit conversions to numeric types that have less precision.

As Jon noted, you will have no way to actually set it to a value larger than `ulong.MaxValue` without some string manipulation. You will also have to represent in internally in some form (string? A number of `ulongs`?) and make sure all conversions and operations work correctly (what about overflows?).

Answer (score 17):

No, you can't create your own form of literal in C#.

You *could* have an implicit conversion from `int`, `long`, `uint` and `ulong`, allowing:

```
Int128 a = 100;
```

but you wouldn't be able to specify values greater than `ulong.MaxValue` that way.

Having an implicit conversion from `decimal` would allow a larger range, but would be a bad idea because you would lose data for any value which wasn't just an integer.

Basically there's nothing which will allow a literal guaranteed-to-be-integer value greater than `ulong.MaxValue` - you could parse a string, but that's not really ideal. Alternatively you could create a constructor which took *two* ulongs, one for the bottom 64 bits and one for the top 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do suffix initialisation. That bit of cuteness will be available in the forthcoming C++ standard ... but I digress.

The most obvious choices are `Int128(long hi, ulong lo)` and `Int128(string)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the new BigInteger struct in 4.0 for tips on initialization. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx