# How to parse a binary string to a binary literal in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, binary, cryptography, biginteger

Here is my specific problem. I need to represent an integer (like 1,2,3,..) as a binary literal with exactly 128 bits.

This is my string representing 1 in binary:
string = "000...0001"; // 128 characters. all zeros until the last 1

Intended result:
bx000...0001;

This issue is that 128 bits is larger than normal types like int, double, decimal, etc. Thus, I believe you must use the BigInteger class to hold this binary value??

Another way to frame this: How can I make sure my BigInteger value is 16 bytes big?

BigInteger val = new BigInteger(1); // but must be 16 bytes exactly.

Comment: A BigInteger is a the size of one BigInteger. In memory it will certainly take up more than 16 bytes. Why do you care how many bytes it uses?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net

Answer (score 0):

You would have to specify the number of bytes and pad whatever is missing with 0's, then you can use the BitArray to get the bit values.  Something like this.

```
public static string GetBitString(BigInteger val, int bytes)
{
    byte[] arrayBytes = new byte[bytes];
    var valBytes = val.ToByteArray();
    for (var i = 0; i < valBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        arrayBytes[i] = valBytes[i];
    }
    var arr = new BitArray(arrayBytes);
    return $"bx{string.Join("", arr.Cast<bool>().Reverse().Select(c => c ? "1" : "0"))}";
}
```

Another options is to just resize the array created to be 16 bytes. Something like this

```
public static string GetBitString(BigInteger val, int bytes)
{
    var valBytes = val.ToByteArray();
    Array.Resize(ref valBytes, bytes);
    return $"bx{string.Join("", new BitArray(valBytes).Cast<bool>().Reverse().Select(c => c ? "1" : "0"))}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ToBinaryString` extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15447131/2557128) modified to skip leading zeros and not force a sign zero, you can just use `PadLeft` to ensure you have leading zeroes:

```
public static string ToBinaryString(this BigInteger bigint) {
    var bytes = bigint.ToByteArray();

    // Create a StringBuilder having appropriate capacity.
    var base2 = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 8);

    // Convert remaining bytes adding leading zeros.
    var idx = bytes.Length - 1;
    for (; idx > 0 && bytes[idx] == 0; --idx)
        ;
    for (; idx >= 0; --idx)
        base2.Append(Convert.ToString(bytes[idx], 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));

    return base2.ToString();
}
```

Then with the prefix and the left padding:

```
var ans = "bx"+val.ToBinaryString().PadLeft(128, '0');
```