# 128-bit data type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, 128-bit

In which data type can I store a 128-bit data in c#?

For example

```
dataType bit128 = 340282366920938463463374607431768211455;
```

What will be the datatype?

Comment: Two longs (packed in a struct)? A byte array? BigInteger? What exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for BigInteger? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Int128 in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using BigInteger

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0

> The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an
> arbitrarily large integer whose value in theory has no upper or lower
> bounds."
>
> ```
> string positiveString = "91389681247993671255432112000000";
> string negativeString = "-90315837410896312071002088037140000";
> BigInteger posBigInt = 0;
> BigInteger negBigInt = 0;
>
> try {
>    posBigInt = BigInteger.Parse(positiveString);
>    Console.WriteLine(posBigInt);
> }
> catch (FormatException)
> {
>    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.",
>                      positiveString);
> }
>
> if (BigInteger.TryParse(negativeString, out negBigInt))
>   Console.WriteLine(negBigInt);
> else
>    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.",
>                       negativeString);
>
> // The example displays the following output:
> //   9.1389681247993671255432112E+31
> //   -9.0315837410896312071002088037E+34
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you have .NET Core 7.0 Preview 5 or newer than you can simply use [`System.Int128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0) or [`System.UInt128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint128?view=net-7.0)

They were implemented in [Add support for Int128 and UInt128 data types](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67151)

For some reason [.NET 7 Preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-preview-5/) [announcement](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7441) didn't include those types, but in the upcoming .NET 7 Preview 6 announcement there'll also be [`Int128Converter` and `UInt128Converter`](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7454) for the new types in Preview 5

They didn't have [C# support](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/#types-without-language-support) yet though, just like `System.Half`, so you'll have to use `Int128` explicitly instead of using a native C# keyword