# Store biginteger (total length =15) values in string variable

Tags: c#

```
public string verylongNumber = "";
```

Here can I assign a variable "verylongNumber" to bigint values ?

In my database I have `bigint` values returned from function, so can I assign `bigint` values directly to string variable?

For example:

```
verylongNumber  = getDBValues();

**verylongNumber  = 501000000111337; // (this value returned from function)** is this valid?
```

Here the `getDBValues()` function calls the database and gets the BIGINT value from the table which is BIGINT column.

Comment: Doesn't `Convert.ToString()` work? Else you have to give a bit more information: What database do you use and what drivers to access it? Is getDBValues your own code?

Comment: thanks for the response, its SQL server and table has BigINT column values which are 15 numbers in length. Yes getDBValues is sample function which connects to database and get the column value which is BIGINT

Comment: 15 digits aren't big at all and can be completely fit in a `Int64` which can store 19 digits. If you want even more then [there's already `Int128` in the latest .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/227731/995714)

Comment: Sounds like you should just try and find out. Depending on your database and method of deserialization to object it might just work, or you might need an explicit conversion - Fastest way to check is just to code it and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `BigInt` in Microsoft SQL Server corresponds to type `long` alias `Int64` in C#.

Use `Convert.ToString()` to convert from `long` to `string`.

Use `Convert.ToInt64()` to convert from `string` to `long`.

Comment: yes there are no reason to use `BigInteger` in C# when the values just fit in 64 bits

Comment: so in that case I should not be using string verylongNumber for direct assignment instead I should convert to Convert.ToString()  like string verylongNumber  = Convert.ToString("501000000111337");

Comment: is that correct ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. You have to explain that better. If you have problems with the English language, try to find a friend who can translate what you are asking into proper English.