# Storing deltas for Unsigned Longs

Tags: c#, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I am writing a class that has a bunch of metric properties of `ulong` data type

```
class Metrics {
  public ulong Memory
  public ulong Handles
  public ulong Calls
}
```

The reason I use `ulong` is because it's a fact that those values are unsigned and the capacity of signed will not be enough.

But I also initiate another instance of this class to store Deltas of those values, the change between the last check and the current.

The problem I am having is that sometimes the number can go down, thus the delta is a negative value, but I cannot store it on the `ulong`.
Even if I declare the Delta as a regular LONG, if number goes up to the ulong max from 0 it will not fit and will throw an error.

How could I accomplish storing the delta value of a ulong knowing this?

```
class myData {
   public Metrics Deltas
   public Metrics Data

   ulong myValue = ulong.MaxValue;
   Deltas.Calls = (myValue - Data.Calls);
   Data.Calls = myValue;
   // Delta will be +MaxValue

   myValue = 0;
   Deltas.Calls = (myValue - Data.Calls);
   Data.Calls = myValue;
   // Delta will be -MaxValue, unsigned, cannot store it

}
```

Comment: Q: Why don't you just a) store "current" values as ulongs in one class instance, b) store "new" values as ulongs in another, different instance, and c) compute the deltas on the fly, using signed arithmetic?  PS: A Win32 "ulong" is 32 bits.  But  C# ulong is 64 bits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types.  Q: Do you really need 64 bits?

Comment: Then don't use checked operations in a checked context.

Comment: Do you need to know the sign or just the abs(delta)?

Comment: @DaveS I need to know the sign, to know if it went up or down.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thats a good point, I also tried that, but even then, when using 64 bit ulong (yes, I need that long) I cannot substract 0 - ulong.Max  and store it on a signed data type, right?

Comment: Short answer is you can't. You need one more bit to represent the delta between two unsigned values because as you noted it can go up or down. So add a boolean for negative/positive and compute the delta in such a way that it's always positive (a-b) or (b-a).

Comment: @IanMercer wrapping ulong and bool in a struct like that would be the most efficient way until .NET Core 7.0 where [Int128](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int128?view=net-7.0) is introduced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding/subtracting two 64-bit numbers produces a 65-bit result, so just use [Int128](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73005626/995714) if you use .NET Core 7.0 Preview 5 or newer. And don't use `class` if you just need to store data like this, a `struct` or `record` would be far better because they can live on stack

```
struct Metrics {
  public Int128 Memory
  public Int128 Handles
  public Int128 Calls
}

class myData {
   public Metrics Deltas
   public Metrics Data

   Int128 myValue = ulong.MaxValue;
   Deltas.Calls = myValue - Data.Calls;
   Data.Calls = myValue;

   myValue = 0;
   Deltas.Calls = myValue - Data.Calls;
   Data.Calls = myValue;
}
```

---

If you're on an old .NET framework then the most efficient solution is to implement your own 65-bit data type. It should be very simple because for printing and sorting purposes multiplication and division won't be needed. You just need to implement `+`/`-` and comparison operators like this

```
public readonly struct Delta
{
    private readonly ulong magnitude;
    private readonly bool sign; // true: negative

    public Delta(ulong magn, bool sgn)
    {
        sign = sgn;
        magnitude = magn;
    }
    public Delta(ulong a)
    {
        sign = false;
        magnitude = a;
    }

    public static Delta operator +(Delta a) => a;
    public static Delta operator -(Delta a) => new Delta(a.magnitude, !a.sign);

    public static Delta operator +(Delta a, Delta b)
    {
        if (a.sign == b.sign)
        {
            var m = a.magnitude + b.magnitude;
            if (m < a.magnitude) // overflow
            {
                sign = !sign;
            }
            return new Delta(m, a.sign);
        }
        var max = Math.Max(a.magnitude, b.magnitude);
        var min = Math.Min(a.magnitude, b.magnitude);
        var sign = a.sign;
        var m = max.magnitude - min.magnitude;
        if (m > max.magnitude) // overflow
        {
            sign = !sign;
        }
        
        return new Delta(max - min, sign);
    }
    public static Delta operator -(Delta a, Delta b) => a + (-b);
    
    public static bool operator ==(Delta a, Delta b)
    {
        return a.magnitude == b.magnitude && a.sign == b.sign;
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Delta a, Delta b) => !(a == b);
    
    public static bool operator >(Delta a, Delta b)
    {
        return a.sign == b.sign ? a.sign ^ (a.magnitude > b.magnitude) b.sign;
    }
    public static bool operator <(Delta a, Delta b) => !(a > b);
    
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return sign ? $"-{magnitude}" : $"{magnitude}";
    }
}

 // Get delta of a and b
public Delta GetDelta(ulong a, Delta ulong b)
{
    return Delta(a) - Delta(b);
}
```

Comment: A very nice implemenation of a 65-bit datatype. +1 (I love this shorthand of `return b.sign` within the `operator >`)

Comment: You forgot to change the implementation of the `<` operator. Also, the ternary statement in the `>` operator could be shortened to `a.sign ^ (a.magnitude > b.magnitude)`

Comment: @JeanotZubler thanks. I thought about `a.sign ^...` in the `operator+` implementation but didn't think about it in `<`

Answer (score 2):

Try use [BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0)

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

public struct Metrics {
  public BigInteger Memory { get; set; }
  public BigInteger Handles { get; set; }
  public BigInteger Calls { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{   
    public static void Main()
    {
        Metrics deltas = new Metrics();     
        Metrics data = new Metrics();

        Console.WriteLine("data.Calls: " + data.Calls);

        BigInteger myValue = UInt64.MaxValue;
        Console.WriteLine("myValue (UInt64.MaxValue): " + myValue);

        deltas.Calls = myValue - data.Calls;    
        Console.WriteLine("deltas.Calls (myValue-data.Calls): " + deltas.Calls);

        data.Calls = myValue;
        Console.WriteLine("data.Calls (myValue): " + data.Calls);
       
        
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
                
        Console.WriteLine("data.Calls: " + data.Calls);

        myValue = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("myValue: " + myValue);

        deltas.Calls = myValue - data.Calls;
        Console.WriteLine("deltas.Calls (myValue-data.Calls): " + deltas.Calls);

        data.Calls = myValue;
        Console.WriteLine("data.Calls (myValue): " + data.Calls);

    }
}
```

Result:

```
data.Calls: 0
myValue (UInt64.MaxValue): 18446744073709551615
deltas.Calls (myValue-data.Calls): 18446744073709551615
data.Calls (myValue): 18446744073709551615

data.Calls: 18446744073709551615
myValue: 0
deltas.Calls (myValue-data.Calls): -18446744073709551615
data.Calls (myValue): 0
```

Comment: Lovely, I didn't know about that data type honestly, good trick and works as expected.

Comment: BigInteger would be far too expensive for this. Int128 is much faster and smaller

Comment: @phuclv, Correct. If we know the highest limit of the data we will store, using variables with memory above close to the highest limit is better because it saves memory, but if we do not know the highest limit then using BigInteger is more safer. Example UInt128.MaxValue * UInt128.MaxValue will failed when use UInt128 to store result, but not when use BigInteger.

Comment: @Ihdina the limits are known which is [-ulong.MaxValue, ulong.MaxValue]. You can't exceed 65 bits when adding/subtracting 64-bit numbers

Comment: @phuclv If they only use the subtraction operation, they can use Int128 because it is more than enough. But when there is a multiplication operation, you should use BigInteger so that it does not overflow.

Comment: yes if the deltas are to be multiplied with 64-bit multipliers. If the range of the multiplier is smaller then it'll be find. Or if we just need to multiply two ulong then UInt128 would also be enough